# Adding more fields to Meteor user accounts

Tags: meteor, user-accounts

I am using `mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown` and `mrt add accounts-password` to get a simple login page running on my app.

The accounts users gives me a nice hash containing ids, createdAt, emails, etc.

If I wanted to add other fields in this hash so I can make use of them later, how would I do that? For example, I want then to also enter their given name and surname:

"given_name": "John", "surname": "Doe"

Answer (score 41):

Users are special objects in meteor ; you don't want to add fields in the user but in the users profile.

From the doc :

```
By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile.
```

If you want to add properties like surname when you create the account, you should use in the `Account.onCreateUser` server-side hook : http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
    //pass the surname in the options

    user.profile['surname'] = options.surname

    return user
}
```

If you want to update a user after, you can do it from the client that way :

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, { $set: {what you want to update} });
```

By default, the users base will allow that (the current user may update itself). If you don't trust your users and want to ensure that everything is properly update, you can also forbid any updates from the client and make them via a `Meteor.call()` and proceed to the checkings server-side. But this would be sad.

---

**Edit :**

As said in the comments, adding options via the standard account-ui won't be possible. You'll only be able to update the user after the registration. To add options when you subscribe, you'll have to make you own form.

I won't insult you by writing html markup, but here is what you want to have after the submit event (and after the various checking) :

```
var options = {
    username: $('input#username')[0].value,
    emails: [{
        address: $('input#email')[0].value,
        verified: false
    }],
    password: $('input#password')[0].value,
    profile: {
        surname: $('input#surname')
    },
};
Accounts.createUser( options , function(err){
    if( err ) $('div#errors').html( err.message );
});
```

You only need the account-base package ; not the account-ui.

Login with the social networks is cake :

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
    requestPermissions: ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_location']
}, function(error){loginCallBack(error);});
```

---

**About the answer ram1 made :**

This is not the way meteor works. You do not "POST" a form. You want all your client / server communication done via the websocket. The equivalent of what you are talking about is making a "Meteor.call('myserverfunction', myarguments, mycallback)" of a server method from the client and you pass the arguments you want the server to use.

But this is not the way you will get the best of meteor. There is the philosophy you want to work with :

1. you have datas in your local mini mongo you got from the server
2. you update locally those datas in your base / view
3. meteor do his magic to transmit those updates to the server
4. there the server can answer : ok, updates saved, this is seamless for you. Or answer : nop ! reverse the changes (and you can implement an error notification system)

(it can answer no because you don't have the permission to update this field, because this update break a rule you did set up...)

All you do is setting permissions and controls on the databases server-side. That way, when an honest client make an update, he sees the result instantly ; way before it has been pushed to the server and send to the other clients. This is ***latency compensation***, one of the seven principles of meteor.

If you modify a data via Meteor.call, you will do that :

1. send an update to the server
2. the server checks and update the base
3. the server send the update to the clients (including you)
4. your local base updates and your view update => you see your update

=> this is what you had in yesterday app ; meteor allow you to build a today app. Don't apply the old recipes :)

Comment: This is an excellent answer.  However, the caveat I would supply is that the OP would need to pass an `options` argument to a client-side `Accounts.createUser` call, as you point out, but this may not be completely trivial if he's relying on the `accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown` package, which will probably be handling that call for him.  I'm not familiar with the package, and anyway there will be an easyish way round this (even if it involves forking), but nevertheless I think he will need to dig into the package a bit more than you suggest.

Comment: If he wants to add fields when the user is registering, he has to make his own registration form ; the standard on from the base package won't do that easily. Just because it would require to add fields. I edit my answer to explain how to :)

Comment: It seems like this explanation of Meteor.call is only correct if the method called is stored purely in server code. 

Put the methods in your lib account so that they're available on both client and server, and latency compensation should work fine. :) 

Otherwise you can get into allow/deny rules, though that seems actually messier than calling isomorphic Meteor methods.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer has the HOW right, but the WHERE is outdated information. (Yes, this would be better as a comment on the answer, but I can't do that yet.)

From the [Meteor 1.2 documentation](http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data):

> The best way to store your custom data onto the Meteor.users collection is to add a new uniquely-named top-level field on the user document.

And regarding using Meteor.user.profile to store custom information:

> Don’t use profile
>
> There’s a tempting existing field called profile that is added by
>   default when a new user registers. This field was historically
>   intended to be used as a scratch pad for user-specific data - maybe
>   their image avatar, name, intro text, etc. Because of this, the
>   profile field on every user is automatically writeable by that user
>   from the client. It’s also automatically published to the client for
>   that particular user.

Basically, it's probably fine to store basic information such as name, address, dob, etc in the profile field, but not a good idea to store anything beyond that as it will, by default, be writeable by the client and vulnerable to malicious users.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and managed to do it only with `Accounts.createUser`:

```
Accounts.createUser({
    email: email,
    password: password,
    profile: {
            givenName: 'John',
            surname: 'Doe',
            gender: 'M'
        }
}
```

Thats very simple way and it works. Just add your desired variables in the profile section and it should be ready. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This simply works. I guess profile is the file that can be customized by default.

Comment: Thanks, using `email` instead of the `emails` array in the top voted answer solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/accounts-entry which offers an `extraSignUpFields` `config` option.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation (https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/blob/master/README.md):

**Custom signup options**

You can define additional input fields to appear in the signup form, and you can decide wether to save these values to the profile object of the user document or not. Specify an array of fields using Accounts.ui.config like so:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {},
    extraSignupFields: [{
        fieldName: 'first-name',
        fieldLabel: 'First name',
        inputType: 'text',
        visible: true,
        validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
          if (!value) {
            errorFunction("Please write your first name");
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
    }, {
        fieldName: 'last-name',
        fieldLabel: 'Last name',
        inputType: 'text',
        visible: true,
    }, {
        fieldName: 'gender',
        showFieldLabel: false,      // If true, fieldLabel will be shown before radio group
        fieldLabel: 'Gender',
        inputType: 'radio',
        radioLayout: 'vertical',    // It can be 'inline' or 'vertical'
        data: [{                    // Array of radio options, all properties are required
            id: 1,                  // id suffix of the radio element
            label: 'Male',          // label for the radio element
            value: 'm'              // value of the radio element, this will be saved.
          }, {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Female',
            value: 'f',
            checked: 'checked'
        }],
        visible: true
    }, {
        fieldName: 'country',
        fieldLabel: 'Country',
        inputType: 'select',
        showFieldLabel: true,
        empty: 'Please select your country of residence',
        data: [{
            id: 1,
            label: 'United States',
            value: 'us'
          }, {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Spain',
            value: 'es',
        }],
        visible: true
    }, {
        fieldName: 'terms',
        fieldLabel: 'I accept the terms and conditions',
        inputType: 'checkbox',
        visible: true,
        saveToProfile: false,
        validate: function(value, errorFunction) {
            if (value) {
                return true;
            } else {
                errorFunction('You must accept the terms and conditions.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The official Meteor Guide provides a comprehensive answer with an example code:

> The best way to store your custom data onto the Meteor.users collection is to add a new uniquely-named top-level field on the user document.

https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data